# Pandas dataframe to sparse matrix based on group assignment (1 if in group, 0 if not in group)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    user      community
    abc       A
    abc       A
    abc       B
    def       A
    def       A
    def       B
    def       C
    ghi       A
    ghi       D
...
```

Based on the `user` column and the `community` column, I would like to create an `n x n` matrix for the `community` column, where each row contains information about the number of shared, unique, users for each community.

In my example, community A has 3 unique neighbors, because users `abc`, `def`, and `ghi` all are connected to community A (the number of times they are connected does not matter for my purposes), community B has 2 shared users, and community D has 1 shared user.

I'm imagining a matrix that looks like this:

```
    A    B    C    D
A  ...  ...  ...  ...
B  ...  ...  ...  ... 
C  ...  ...  ...  ...
D  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

...where the `...` are the number of common users for each community.

I am completely lost on this point. I am trying to prepare my data for network analysis, but cannot obtain the results I need.

I've looked around and found helpful articles related to crosstabs and co-occurrence matrices, but they aren't returning the desired results.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do `dot`

```
df=df.drop_duplicates()
s=pd.crosstab(df.community,df.user)
s.dot(s.T.gt(0))
Out[330]: 
community  A  B  C  D
community            
A          3  2  1  1
B          2  2  1  0
C          1  1  1  0
D          1  0  0  1
```